# Declaring a class with inhertiance final

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to declare a class (`Bar`) that inherits from anther class (`BarBase`) `final`? Or does C++ limit it declaring the individual methods `final` when a class inherits from another class (with virtual methods).

```
class BarBase
{
public:
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

class Bar : public BarBase final // not legal to add 'final' here, why?
{
public:
    void DoSomething(); final // Legal to add 'final' here, but doing it for every method is less than ideal.
};
```

Comment: Making a member function `final`, shouldn't it be done *before* the semicolon?

Comment: As for your problem, see e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final).

Comment: `class Bar final : public BarBase { ... };`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As state in the comment, the keyword `final` is misplaced. The correct syntax is:

```
class Bar final : public BarBase 
{
    // ...
};
```